# Вывод проекта Laravel в production (отключение вывода ошибок и т.д.)

Tags: php, laravel

Уже поставил в .env эти параметры, но все равно ошибки выводятся, хотя не должны, так как это угроза безопасности - весь код видно, точнее это просто не должно выводиться.

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Как правильно вывести сайт в продакшн в Laravel чтобы не было таких косяков вообще?

Comment: artisan config:clear

Comment: Если конечно у вас дебаг не прописан вручную в конфигах

Comment: @Walfter получилось, спасибо большое) Напишите ответ чтобы я выделил, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конифиги кешируются системой, для сброса кеша конфигов есть команда

```
php artisan config:clear
```